# How can I determine whether page (in Opera panel) is visible to user?

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I try to create a page that will show in a sidebar panel in Opera. I'd like to know when user sees it or not. The problem is when a user closes the panel the page is still active - all javascript functions run - I need to stop them when user closes the panel.

Comment: From my understading of your point, I would use a div to embed your side panel stuff and set it to a 2 position state, like "true/false" if activated/deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not realy detect that. Test the window size when the panel is closed.
To detect active tab in browsers you can use mousemove or mouseover events.
but it dose not work when the mouse is out of your window.

Comment: I tried to test the window size in many ways, and I always get the same result I get when the panel is opened.